# ASP.NET Core app on IIS - where are the error stack traces logged?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, error-logging

I have published an ASP.NET Core app to IIS on Windows Service 2016. The problem is that I cannot find where are stored error logs, i.e. in my app I got 500 internal server error I want to know where is detailed stack trace of this error in logs on the server. Do I have to configure something to enable logging error details?

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you want to look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2#troubleshoot-app-startup-errors

To enable trace logging, you need to modify your web.config:

```
<aspNetCore ...>
  <handlerSettings>
    <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="file" />
    <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value="c:\temp\ancm.log" />
  </handlerSettings>
</aspNetCore>
```

Alternatively, you can simply run the app from the command line by opening a command prompt to your site directory and running:

> dotnet MyApp.dll

You'll be able to see any exceptions raised and their stack traces in the command prompt window.